# Changing prefab instances through script

Tags: c#, game-engine, unity-game-engine

I made a prefab gameObject with a rigidbody component attached. **Whenever I change the mass of the original prefab from the inspector, all the instances present in the scene get affected (the field is not overridden). But when I try to do the same thing using a script, the mass of the instances remain unchanged** (only the main prefab is affected and every time I enter play mode, it retains its previous value!). The script is attached to another gameObject and looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CubeScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject largeCube; // dragged the original prefab in the inspector
    private Rigidbody rb;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {

        rb = (Rigidbody) largeCube.GetComponent ("Rigidbody");
        rb.mass = 44; // this is not changing the instances, rather only the main prefab. Note that the mass is not overridden

    }

}
```

I don't understand as a beginner. Please explain this to me.

Comment: Can you try `rb = largeCube.GetComponent<RigidBody>()` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I belieive that "Apply" button is responsible for applying all values to the instances of prefab at the inspector level. From the script, you need to do it manually (You don't have any button or method called "Apply").

The best (and most efficient in my opinion) is to create tag for prefab and the usage of

```
GameObject[] myPrefabInstances = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("yourTagName").
```

And then:

```
foreach (var go in myPrefabInstances) 
{
        var rb = (Rigidbody) go.GetComponent ("Rigidbody");
        rb.mass = 44;
}
```

Comment: That pretty much works. So does this one:
`Rigidbody[] rigidbodies = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Rigidbody)) as Rigidbody[];

  foreach(Rigidbody rb in rigidbodies)
      {
                 rb.mass = 44;
      }
`
But could you please explain the differences a little more?

Comment: According to unity forums, `FindGameObjectsWithTag` is faster than `FindObjectsOfType`.

Comment: I mean- why didn't my first code work, the one described in the main question? The tutorials say that it is the same whether you change something from the inspector or using a script like that.